# why showing this error in output in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

why showing this error in output in Netbeans or is it just normal??

ant -f C:\Users\Orange\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AntFarm -Dnb.internal.action.name=run run
init:
Deleting: C:\Users\Orange\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AntFarm\build\built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: C:\Users\Orange\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AntFarm\build\built-jar.properties
compile:

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that is an error?

Comment: i mean... it did not show up in other cases....

Comment: If you run your app with ant, that kind of output is something normal...